# mysql procedure order by clause conditional

Tags: mysql, sql

good day,

how to make the sql code below a conditional one changing asc or desc value:

```
ORDER BY
  inventory_quantity.product_color_name DESC
```

i've tried case statement but got error

```
ORDER BY
  CASE product_color_name_sort WHEN product_color_name_sort = 'asc' THEN inventory_quantity.product_color_name END ASC
```

also tried if statement but still error

```
ORDER BY
  inventory_quantity.product_color_name IF(product_color_name_sort = 'asc', 'ASC', 'DESC')
```

is this possible?

procedure code

```
delimiter //

  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
  PROCEDURE `stocks_quantities`(
    IN `depot_id` INT, 
    IN `qa` INT, 
    IN `product_dimension_id` INT, 
    IN `product_color_id` INT, 
    IN `product_unit_name` INT, 
    IN `product_status_id` INT, 
    IN `product_name_sort` VARCHAR(10) CHARSET utf8, 
    IN `product_color_name_sort` VARCHAR(10) CHARSET utf8, 
    IN `product_dimension_name_sort` VARCHAR(10) CHARSET utf8, 
    IN `i_limit` INT, 
    IN `i_offset` INT
    )

      NO SQL
      begin

      DECLARE i_limit_temp INT DEFAULT 0;
      SET i_limit_temp = COALESCE(NULLIF(i_limit, ''));

      IF i_limit = 0 OR i_limit = '' OR i_limit IS NULL THEN
          SET i_limit_temp = 1000;
      END IF;

      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        (
          SELECT
            products.id AS 'product_id',
            products.name AS 'product_name',
            products.model AS 'product_model',
            products.qty_low_alert AS 'product_qty_low_alert',
            COALESCE(tbl_included_inventories.product_total,0) AS 'included_inventory_total', 
            COALESCE(tbl_received_pos.product_total,0) AS 'received_po_total', 
            COALESCE(tbl_received_tos.product_total,0) AS 'received_to_total', 
            COALESCE(tbl_excluded_inventories.product_total,0) AS 'excluded_inventory_total', 
            COALESCE(tbl_transfer_orders.product_total,0) AS 'transfer_order_total', 
            COALESCE(tbl_official_receipts.product_total,0) AS 'official_receipt_total', 
            COALESCE(tbl_missed_pos.product_total,0) AS 'missed_purchased_order_total', 
            COALESCE(tbl_purchase_orders.product_total,0) AS 'purchased_order_total', 
            COALESCE(tbl_wrong_send_pos.product_total,0) AS 'wrong_send_purchased_order_total', 
            COALESCE(tbl_sales_returns.product_total,0) AS 'sales_return_total', 
            (
              COALESCE(tbl_purchase_orders.product_total,0)
              -
              (
                COALESCE(tbl_received_pos.product_total,0)
                +
                COALESCE(tbl_missed_pos.product_total,0)
              )
            ) AS 'af',
            (
              COALESCE(tbl_excluded_inventories.product_total,0) +
              COALESCE(tbl_transfer_orders.product_total,0) +
              COALESCE(tbl_official_receipts.product_total,0)
            ) AS 'tr', 
            (
              COALESCE(tbl_included_inventories.product_total,0) +
              COALESCE(tbl_received_pos.product_total,0) +
              COALESCE(tbl_received_tos.product_total,0) +
              COALESCE(tbl_sales_returns.product_total,0)
            ) -
            (
              COALESCE(tbl_excluded_inventories.product_total,0) +
              COALESCE(tbl_transfer_orders.product_total,0) +
              COALESCE(tbl_official_receipts.product_total,0)
            )
            + COALESCE(tbl_wrong_send_pos.product_total,0)
            AS 'qa',
            tbl_product_colors.id AS product_color_id,
            tbl_product_dimensions.id AS product_dimension_id,
            products.product_status_id AS product_status_id,
            tbl_product_colors.name AS product_color_name,
            tbl_product_dimensions.name AS product_dimension_name,
            tbl_product_units.name AS product_unit_name
          FROM 
            products
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                included_inventory_details.product_id,
                SUM(included_inventory_details.quantity_included) AS product_total
              FROM
                  included_inventories
              LEFT JOIN
                  included_inventory_details
                  ON
                  included_inventories.id = included_inventory_details.included_inventory_id
              WHERE 
                  included_inventories.depot_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(depot_id, ''), included_inventories.depot_id)
              GROUP BY
                included_inventory_details.product_id
            )
            AS tbl_included_inventories ON tbl_included_inventories.product_id = products.id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                received_po_details.product_id,
                SUM(received_po_details.quantity_received) AS product_total
              FROM
                received_pos
              LEFT JOIN
                received_po_details
                ON
                received_pos.id = received_po_details.received_po_id  
              WHERE 
                  received_pos.depot_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(depot_id, ''), received_pos.depot_id)
              GROUP BY
                received_po_details.product_id  
            )
            AS tbl_received_pos ON tbl_received_pos.product_id = products.id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                received_to_details.product_id,
                SUM(received_to_details.quantity_received) AS product_total
              FROM
                received_tos
              LEFT JOIN
                received_to_details
                ON
                received_tos.id = received_to_details.received_to_id  
              WHERE 
                  received_tos.depot_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(depot_id, ''), received_tos.depot_id)
              GROUP BY
                received_to_details.product_id
            )
            AS tbl_received_tos ON tbl_received_tos.product_id = products.id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                excluded_inventory_details.product_id,
                SUM(excluded_inventory_details.quantity_excluded) AS product_total
              FROM
                excluded_inventories
              LEFT JOIN
                excluded_inventory_details
                ON
                excluded_inventories.id = excluded_inventory_details.excluded_inventory_id  
              WHERE 
                  excluded_inventories.depot_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(depot_id, ''), excluded_inventories.depot_id)
              GROUP BY
                excluded_inventory_details.product_id  
            )
            AS tbl_excluded_inventories ON tbl_excluded_inventories.product_id = products.id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                transfer_order_details.product_id,
                SUM(transfer_order_details.quantity_transfering) AS product_total
              FROM
                transfer_orders
              LEFT JOIN
                transfer_order_details
                ON
                transfer_orders.id = transfer_order_details.transfer_order_id  
              WHERE 
                  transfer_orders.releasing_depot_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(depot_id, ''), transfer_orders.releasing_depot_id)
              GROUP BY
                transfer_order_details.product_id
            )
            AS tbl_transfer_orders ON tbl_transfer_orders.product_id = products.id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                official_receipt_details.product_id,
                SUM(official_receipt_details.quantity_released) AS product_total
              FROM
                official_receipts
              LEFT JOIN
                official_receipt_details
                ON
                official_receipts.id = official_receipt_details.official_receipt_id  
              WHERE 
                  official_receipts.depot_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(depot_id, ''), official_receipts.depot_id)
              GROUP BY
                official_receipt_details.product_id  
            )
            AS tbl_official_receipts on tbl_official_receipts.product_id = products.id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                missed_po_details.product_id,
                SUM(missed_po_details.quantity_missed) AS product_total
              FROM
                missed_pos
              LEFT JOIN
                missed_po_details
                ON
                missed_pos.id = missed_po_details.missed_po_id  
              WHERE 
                  missed_pos.depot_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(depot_id, ''), missed_pos.depot_id)
              GROUP BY
                missed_po_details.product_id  
            )
            AS tbl_missed_pos ON tbl_missed_pos.product_id = products.id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                purchase_order_details.product_id,
                SUM(purchase_order_details.quantity_ordered) AS product_total
              FROM
                purchase_orders
              LEFT JOIN
                purchase_order_details
                ON
                purchase_orders.id = purchase_order_details.purchase_order_id  
              WHERE 
                  purchase_orders.depot_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(depot_id, ''), purchase_orders.depot_id)
              GROUP BY
                purchase_order_details.product_id  
            )
            AS tbl_purchase_orders ON tbl_purchase_orders.product_id = products.id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                wrong_send_po_details.product_id,
                SUM(wrong_send_po_details.quantity_wrong_send) AS product_total
              FROM
                wrong_send_pos
              LEFT JOIN
                wrong_send_po_details
                ON
                wrong_send_pos.id = wrong_send_po_details.wrong_send_po_id  
              WHERE 
                  wrong_send_pos.depot_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(depot_id, ''), wrong_send_pos.depot_id)
              GROUP BY
                wrong_send_po_details.product_id  
            )
            AS tbl_wrong_send_pos ON tbl_wrong_send_pos.product_id = products.id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                sales_return_details.product_id,
                SUM(sales_return_details.quantity_received) AS product_total
              FROM
                sales_returns
              LEFT JOIN
                sales_return_details
                ON
                sales_returns.id = sales_return_details.sales_return_id  
              WHERE 
                  sales_returns.depot_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(depot_id, ''), sales_returns.depot_id)
              GROUP BY
                sales_return_details.product_id  
            )
            AS tbl_sales_returns ON tbl_sales_returns.product_id = products.id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                product_colors.id,
                product_colors.name
              FROM
                product_colors
            )
            AS tbl_product_colors ON tbl_product_colors.id = products.product_color_id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                product_dimensions.id,
                product_dimensions.name
              FROM
                product_dimensions
            )
            AS tbl_product_dimensions ON tbl_product_dimensions.id = products.product_dimension_id
          LEFT JOIN
            (
              SELECT
                product_units.id,
                product_units.name
              FROM
                product_units
            )
            AS tbl_product_units ON tbl_product_units.id = products.product_unit_id
        ) inventory_quantity
      WHERE
        inventory_quantity.qa >= COALESCE(NULLIF(qa, ''), 0)
        AND
        inventory_quantity.product_dimension_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(product_dimension_id, ''), inventory_quantity.product_dimension_id)
        AND
        inventory_quantity.product_color_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(product_color_id, ''), inventory_quantity.product_color_id)
        AND
        inventory_quantity.product_unit_name = COALESCE(NULLIF(product_unit_name, ''), inventory_quantity.product_unit_name)  
        AND
        inventory_quantity.product_status_id = COALESCE(NULLIF(product_status_id, ''), inventory_quantity.product_status_id)
      ORDER BY

        CASE product_name_sort WHEN product_name_sort = 'asc' THEN inventory_quantity.product_name END ASC,
        CASE product_name_sort WHEN product_name_sort = 'desc' THEN inventory_quantity.product_name END DESC,

        CASE product_color_name_sort WHEN product_color_name_sort = 'asc' THEN inventory_quantity.product_color_name END ASC,
        CASE product_color_name_sort WHEN product_color_name_sort = 'desc' THEN inventory_quantity.product_color_name END DESC,

        CASE product_dimension_name_sort WHEN product_dimension_name_sort = 'asc' THEN inventory_quantity.product_dimension_name END ASC,
        CASE product_dimension_name_sort WHEN product_dimension_name_sort = 'desc' THEN inventory_quantity.product_dimension_name END DESC

      LIMIT 
        i_limit_temp
      OFFSET
        i_offset;


      end; //
delimiter ;
```

thanks

Comment: @FelixPamittan
actually your solution was my first code block but the sql is not returning anything

Comment: It's not. Yours has a syntax error. Also if it's not returning anything, then it's a problem with the `SELECT` statement. `ORDER BY` only affects the sorting.

Comment: @FelixPamittan i've updated my post to show you my procedure. We have the same case statement in order by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally got it

```
CASE
  when product_name_sort <> 'asc' then 0
  when product_name_sort = 'asc' then inventory_quantity.product_name
END ASC,       
CASE
  when product_name_sort <> 'desc' then 0
  when product_name_sort = 'desc' then inventory_quantity.product_name
END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your `CASE` expression:

```
CASE product_color_name_sort WHEN product_color_name_sort = 'asc' THEN inventory_quantity.product_color_name END ASC
```

should be:

```
CASE WHEN product_color_name_sort = 'asc' THEN inventory_quantity.product_color_name END ASC
```

With regards to the conditional ordering, here is one way to do it:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN product_color_name_sort = 'asc' THEN inventory_quantity.product_color_name 
    END ASC,
    CASE 
        WHEN product_color_name_sort = 'DESC' THEN inventory_quantity.product_color_name 
    END DESC
```

Comment: If it's not returning anything, then it's a problem with the `SELECT` statement. `ORDER BY` only affects the sorting.

Comment: i get results if I remove the order clase so im sure i dont have problems with my select statement

Answer (score 0):

According MySQL documentation it is not possible.

`[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]`

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Reference2: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html

You can try to move the logic in `SELECT` clause and so order by a new created column

Comment: how can i move the order clause inside select clause?

Comment: not the order clause itself. The idea is to use `IF` statement in `SELECT` (because here you can), to create a field you can sort on.

Comment: but that would only arrange the columns? What I like is the control over ASC or DESC value that will came from a website request. So the asc and desc value should be a parameter.